# Request response changes when using proxy (uses auth) with python-requests, despite no change in browser

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been trying to solve a problem for a while now, was hoping some of you guys could help.

I make a request to a website without a proxy, using python-requests. Using the correct headers, everything identical to the browser. I get a successful response, the same as the browser's response.

However when I update the sessions proxies using session.proxies.update(proxies), I get a completely different response. When using this proxy (requires auth) in the browser, it works as normal. I've set up a Wireshark session on both my local computer and the proxy server. The requests are exactly the same for both the local request and the proxy request. No headers are being added from the proxy server.

Is there something I am overlooking which would explain a different response. As said before, I can access the website using the proxy in a browser, even with javascript turned off, so that's not the issue. Thanks in advance for any help, I really appreciate it

Edit - My Code:

```
url = "https://example.org/post"
proxy = "username:password@proxy-host:proxy-port"
proxies = {
    'http' : 'http://' + proxy,
    'https' : 'https://' + proxy
}

payload = [
('comment', "test")
]
files = [('upfile', "file.jpg", open("file.jpg", 'rb'))]
content_type, body = MultipartFormdataEncoder().encode(payload, files)

headers = OrderedDict([
('Host', 'example.org'),
('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
('Content-Length', str(len(body))),
('Sec-Fetch-Mode', 'cors'),
('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'),
('Content-Type', content_type),
('Accept', '*/*'),
('Origin', 'http://example.org'),
('Sec-Fetch-Site', 'same-site'),
('Referer', 'http://example.org/'),
('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'),
('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.9'),
])
s.headers = headers
s.proxies.update(proxies)
response = s.post(url, body, verify=True)
response_text = response.text
```

Comment: if you add some code that would be more helpful.

Comment: Please make sure to at least some code so we can try / understand what you are trying and maybe help you spot the error.

Comment: Edited the code in. @ParthS007